# Post Not working between Angular and Express

Tags: angular, express, post, get

my get feature seems to be working fine for my website, but the post is struggling to work, it works fine through postman, it just seems that something is wrong with my angular application,

here is the html for the form to input the data :

```
<form [formGroup]="pokemonForm" (ngSubmit) = "onSubmit()" class>


    <button type="button" class="btn-close" aria-label="Close" (click)="closeForm()"></button>

<div class="mb-3">
    <label for="Name" class="form-label"> Name </label>
    <input id="Name" type="text" formControlName="Name" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
    <label for="Generation" class="form-label"> Generation </label>
    <input id="Generation" type="number" formControlName="Generation" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
    <label for="PokedexNo" class="form-label"> PokedexNo </label>
    <input id="PokedexNo" type="number" formControlName="PokedexNo" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
    <label for="Type" class="form-label">Type</label>
    <input id="Type" type="text" formControlName="Type" class="form-control">
</div>

<button type="submit" [disabled]= "pokemonForm" class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>

<!-- <div *ngIf="Name?.invalid && Generation?.touched"  class="alert alert-danger" >
    Title is required and must be more than 3 characters
</div>
<div *ngIf="Name?.invalid && Generation?.touched"  class="alert alert-danger" >
    Please Fill In Details
</div> -->

</form>
```

And here is the services page with the functions

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { IPokemon } from './pokemonmodel';
import { catchError, Observable,of,throwError } from 'rxjs';
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http'



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PokemonService {

  private dataUri = 'http://localhost:3000/pokemons'

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  // pokemon:IPokemon = new IPokemon();

  getPokemons(): Observable<IPokemon[]>{
    console.log("getPokemons is called");

    return this.http.get<IPokemon[]>(`${this.dataUri}?limit=5`)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    )
  }

  addPokemon(pokemon: IPokemon): Observable<IPokemon>{
    return this.http.post<IPokemon>(this.dataUri,pokemon)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    )
  }

  updatePokemon(id: string, pokemon: IPokemon): Observable<IPokemon> {
    console.log('subscribing to update' + id);
    let pokemonURI: string = this.dataUri + '/' + id;
    return this.http.put<IPokemon>(pokemonURI, pokemon)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      )
  }

  deletePokemon(id: string): Observable<unknown> {
    const url = `${this.dataUri}/${id}`; // DELETE 
    return this.http.delete(url)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }  

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse){
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong.
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
        `body was: ${error.error}`);
    }
    // Return an observable with a user-facing error message.
    return throwError(
      'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
    }

    
}
```

[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJMRI.png)

```
core.mjs:7640 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Name')
    at PokemonFormComponent.ngOnInit (pokemon-form.component.ts:24:49)
    at callHook (core.mjs:2491:22)
    at callHooks (core.mjs:2460:17)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.mjs:2411:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:11999:21)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.mjs:13034:17)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:12008:9)
    at refreshComponent (core.mjs:13080:13)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:11774:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:12034:13)
handleError @ core.mjs:7640
(anonymous) @ core.mjs:27486
invoke @ zone.js:372
run @ zone.js:134
runOutsideAngular @ core.mjs:26277
tick @ core.mjs:27486
(anonymous) @ core.mjs:27323
invoke @ zone.js:372
onInvoke @ core.mjs:26378
invoke @ zone.js:371
run @ zone.js:134
run @ core.mjs:26232
next @ core.mjs:27322
next @ Subscriber.js:91
_next @ Subscriber.js:60
next @ Subscriber.js:31
(anonymous) @ Subject.js:34
errorContext @ errorContext.js:19
next @ Subject.js:27
emit @ core.mjs:22886
checkStable @ core.mjs:26300
onLeave @ core.mjs:26428
onInvokeTask @ core.mjs:26372
invokeTask @ zone.js:405
runTask @ zone.js:178
invokeTask @ zone.js:487
invokeTask @ zone.js:1648
globalCallback @ zone.js:1679
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1712
core.mjs:7640 


ERROR Error: NG01052: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

      Example:

      
  <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
    <input formControlName="firstName">
  </div>

  In your class:

  this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
      firstName: new FormControl()
  });
    at missingFormException (forms.mjs:1509:12)
    at FormGroupDirective._checkFormPresent (forms.mjs:5026:19)
    at FormGroupDirective.ngOnChanges (forms.mjs:4799:14)
    at FormGroupDirective.rememberChangeHistoryAndInvokeOnChangesHook (core.mjs:1519:14)
    at callHook (core.mjs:2501:18)
    at callHooks (core.mjs:2460:17)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.mjs:2411:9)
    at selectIndexInternal (core.mjs:9836:17)
    at Module.ɵɵadvance (core.mjs:9819:5)
    at PokemonFormComponent_Template (pokemon-form.component.html:23:23)
handleError @ core.mjs:7640
(anonymous) @ core.mjs:27486
invoke @ zone.js:372
run @ zone.js:134
runOutsideAngular @ core.mjs:26277
tick @ core.mjs:27486
(anonymous) @ core.mjs:27323
invoke @ zone.js:372
onInvoke @ core.mjs:26378
invoke @ zone.js:371
run @ zone.js:134
run @ core.mjs:26232
next @ core.mjs:27322
next @ Subscriber.js:91
_next @ Subscriber.js:60
next @ Subscriber.js:31
(anonymous) @ Subject.js:34
errorContext @ errorContext.js:19
next @ Subject.js:27
emit @ core.mjs:22886
checkStable @ core.mjs:26300
onLeave @ core.mjs:26428
onInvokeTask @ core.mjs:26372
invokeTask @ zone.js:405
runTask @ zone.js:178
invokeTask @ zone.js:487
invokeTask @ zone.js:1648
globalCallback @ zone.js:1679
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1712
4core.mjs:7640 


ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
    at FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.mjs:4852:32)
    at FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.mjs:5409:43)
    at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.mjs:5354:18)
    at FormControlName.rememberChangeHistoryAndInvokeOnChangesHook (core.mjs:1519:14)
    at callHook (core.mjs:2501:18)
    at callHooks (core.mjs:2460:17)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.mjs:2411:9)
    at selectIndexInternal (core.mjs:9836:17)
    at Module.ɵɵadvance (core.mjs:9819:5)
    at PokemonFormComponent_Template (pokemon-form.component.html:23:23)
handleError @ core.mjs:7640
(anonymous) @ core.mjs:27486
invoke @ zone.js:372
run @ zone.js:134
runOutsideAngular @ core.mjs:26277
tick @ core.mjs:27486
(anonymous) @ core.mjs:27323
invoke @ zone.js:372
onInvoke @ core.mjs:26378
invoke @ zone.js:371
run @ zone.js:134
run @ core.mjs:26232
next @ core.mjs:27322
next @ Subscriber.js:91
_next @ Subscriber.js:60
next @ Subscriber.js:31
(anonymous) @ Subject.js:34
errorContext @ errorContext.js:19
next @ Subject.js:27
emit @ core.mjs:22886
checkStable @ core.mjs:26300
onLeave @ core.mjs:26428
onInvokeTask @ core.mjs:26372
invokeTask @ zone.js:405
runTask @ zone.js:178
invokeTask @ zone.js:487
invokeTask @ zone.js:1648
globalCallback @ zone.js:1679
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1712
core.mjs:7640 


ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_syncPendingControls')
    at syncPendingControls (forms.mjs:3228:10)
    at FormGroupDirective.onSubmit (forms.mjs:4948:9)
    at FormGroupDirective_submit_HostBindingHandler (forms.mjs:5031:100)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.mjs:15778:16)
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.mjs:15813:22)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.mjs:459:38)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:26365:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405:60)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:47)
handleError @ core.mjs:7640
handleError @ core.mjs:13387
executeListenerWithErrorHandling @ core.mjs:15781
wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault @ core.mjs:15813
(anonymous) @ platform-browser.mjs:459
invokeTask @ zone.js:406
onInvokeTask @ core.mjs:26365
invokeTask @ zone.js:405
runTask @ zone.js:178
invokeTask @ zone.js:487
invokeTask @ zone.js:1648
globalCallback @ zone.js:1679
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1712
```

Any help is greatly apprecitated I'm not too great at this programming stuff :(

Edit: Here is the component.ts file

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, Output,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { UntypedFormControl, UntypedFormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { IPokemon } from 'src/app/pokemonmodel';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-pokemon-form',
  templateUrl: './pokemon-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pokemon-form.component.css']
})
export class PokemonFormComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() pokemon:IPokemon;
  @Output() pokemonFormClose = new EventEmitter<IPokemon>();
  message: string = "";
  pokemonForm : UntypedFormGroup;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.pokemonForm = new UntypedFormGroup({
      Name: new UntypedFormControl(this.pokemon.Name),
      Type: new UntypedFormControl(this.pokemon.Type),
      Generation: new UntypedFormControl(this.pokemon.Generation),
      PokedexNo: new UntypedFormControl(this.pokemon.PokedexNo)
    })
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log('forms submitted with ');
    console.table(this.pokemonForm?.value);
    this.pokemonFormClose.emit(this.pokemonForm?.value)
  }

  get Name() {
    return this.pokemonForm?.get('Name');
  }

  get Type() {
    return this.pokemonForm?.get('Type');
  }

  get Generation() {
    return this.pokemonForm.get('Generation')
  }

  get PokedexNo() {
    return this.pokemonForm.get('PokedexNo')
  }

  closeForm() {
    this.pokemonFormClose.emit(undefined)

  }

}
```

Comment: Keep learning! I don't see the component TS file (pokemon-form.component.ts). This is likely where the error is coming from.

Comment: The error message points to a missing FormGroup.
Your HTML is looking for a FormGroup called "pokemonForm". Make sure one of those is added to pokemon-form.component.ts. Here's a guide on how to do that: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#using-the-formbuilder-service-to-generate-controls

Comment: @Ryan Hi thanks, for responding, I added it to the post !

Answer (score 0):

There are a few error messages here.

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Name')

This is happening because 'this.pokemon' is undefined.

There are multiple ways to fix this, but the easiest is to add the null check operator (?) to references to 'this.pokemon'.

Basically this checks if pokemon is null, and if it is, then it will set the form to `undefined`. Otherwise it will set the value.

```
this.pokemonForm = new UntypedFormGroup({
      Name: new UntypedFormControl(this.pokemon?.Name),
      Type: new UntypedFormControl(this.pokemon?.Type),
      Generation: new UntypedFormControl(this.pokemon?.Generation),
      PokedexNo: new UntypedFormControl(this.pokemon?.PokedexNo)
    })
```

You may also want to initialize the FormGroup in the constructor. This is the normal place to initialize variables.

Comment: This seems to have fixed the Name error, thank you! No more errors are showing in the console but now it is not letting me press submit haha, one problem to the next it seems

Comment: Yep, that's how it goes! I suggest running the program as you build it. Make little baby steps and each time verify it works. This is easier than trying to write a program - then fix all the errors at the end. I'll look into this next question.

Comment: This is what's disabling it: [disabled]="pokemonForm"
I don't think you need that. You might be looking for [disabled]="!pokemonForm.valid"